# Erlang socket and receive timeout

Tags: sockets, erlang, timeout

How to set receive timeout for socket, i could not find it in the socket option man.
my first soluation to the problem is to put **after** statement.

```
{ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [..,{active, once}...]),
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
loop(Socket).
loop(Socket) ->
  receive
     {tcp, Socket, Data} ->
        inet:setopts(Sock, [{active, once}]),
        loop(Socket);
     {tcp_closed, Socket} -> closed;
     Other -> process_data(Other)
  after 1000 -> time_out
  end.
```

but the socket may never timeout because there are messages from other processes
how can i set timeout without spawning other process ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't specify a receive timeout if you are using active mode. If you need to control receive timeout behavior, switch to passive mode on the socket, i.e. `{active,false}` on the socket options, and then use `gen_tcp:recv` with a receive timeout option.

In addition, a lot of Erlang socket server designs use an Erlang process per client connection. You can see http://www.trapexit.org/Building_a_Non-blocking_TCP_server_using_OTP_principles and http://20bits.com/article/erlang-a-generalized-tcp-server for examples. The OTP provides a lot of great ways to build robust servers with Erlang; take advantage of it!

Answer (score 0):

also you can use prim_inet:async_recv/3 which allow you to receive tcp message with timeout while receving other messages from different processes

```
read(Socket) ->
prim_inet:async_recv(Socket, 0, 1000),
receive
    {inet_async, _ ,_ ,{ok, Msg}} ->
        io:format("message received ~p~n",[Msg]),
        read(Socket);
    {inet_async,_,_,{error,timeout}} ->
        io:format("timeout !"),
        catch gen_tcp:close(Socket);
    {fake, Msg} -> io:format("Message = ~p~n", [Msg]),
                   read(Socket)
end.
```

Comment: About `prim_inet`: "It is undocumented because it is an internal module that is not meant to be called from applications. Its interface may
change without warning in even the smallest patch." Cfr. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13187714/452614)