# what is the difference between gen_tcp:recv and prim_inet recv

Tags: erlang, inet

What is prim_inet module , how it works ?
i tried to google it but i didn't find any useful docs.
i looked at the source file prim_inet.erl but nothing special there , dose prim_inet:async_recv spawn a new process for each recv ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You found no useful documentation because `erlang` modules that are internal and not meant to be directly called from applications aren't documented.

Please see ["Why prim_inet undocumented.](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/why-prim-inet-undocument-td2102408.html)
In that link you will read the following:

> It is undocumented because it is an internal module that is not  ment
>   to be called from applications. Its interface may  change without
>   warning in even the smallest patch.
>
> If there is functionality you need that is not provided  in gen_tcp,
>   gen_udp, gen_sctp, inet etc... you just  ask about it and there may
>   either be another way  to do it, or it may be added to the public 
>   interface where it should be.

However, you might find [prim_inet:async_accept/2](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/prim-inet-async-accept-2-td2113087.html) useful.